# How to code the shiny server to be able to accept direct input from the sidebarPanel and also able to accept uploaded file based on user's preference

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny application that would provide users with the opportunity to run a single computation using the inputs (G and N) from the sidebarPanel, and also can accept an uploaded file to run multiple computations by ID. My challenge is how to configure the server to be able to do both depending on the user’s preference.
I have attached the sample code, function, and data. I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
## Sample data to upload .........
file1 <- data.frame(ID=1:10, G=seq(10,100,10),N=seq(400,1300,100))
write.csv(file1, "file1.csv")

## Sample function .........
func. <- function(G, N){
  z1=exp(2.263+0.865*log(G/N))
  z2=exp(2.475+0.402*log(G/N))
  z3=exp(2.603+0.374*log(G/N))
  z4=exp(2.758+0.358*log(G/N))
  Z <- data.frame(z1,z2,z3,z4)
  return(Z)
}

## The shinyAPP ..........
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Stand"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
  
  h3("Inputs"),
  
  numericInput("G", "G", min=0.00, max=300.00, value=25),
  numericInput("N", "N", min=100, max=1500, value=350),
  
  fileInput("file", "Upload file for batch computation", accept = ".csv"),
  
  actionButton("runScript", "Run")
  ),
  mainPanel(type="tabs",
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dt <- eventReactive(input$runScript,{
    
      result <- func.(input$G, input$N)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    dt()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the problem you encounter? You could simply include a checkbox in the UI and run the function by ID when this checkbox is checked.

Comment: Yes, but the challenge is how to loop through the ID in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way. It takes the data from the uploaded file if there's an uploaded file and then performs the computations by ID, otherwise it takes the data from the numeric inputs. The case when there are more than one observation by ID is handled.

```r
## Sample data to upload .........
file1 <- data.frame(ID=1:10, G=seq(10,100,10),N=seq(400,1300,100))
write.csv(file1, "file1.csv")

## Sample function .........
func. <- function(G, N){
  z1=exp(2.263+0.865*log(G/N))
  z2=exp(2.475+0.402*log(G/N))
  z3=exp(2.603+0.374*log(G/N))
  z4=exp(2.758+0.358*log(G/N))
  Z <- data.frame(z1,z2,z3,z4)
  return(Z)
}

func_byID <- function(dat) {
  dataframes <- split(dat, dat$ID) # split the data by ID
  results <- lapply(dataframes, function(df) { # apply func. to each subdata
    func.(df$G, df$N)
  })
  result <- do.call(rbind, results) # stack the results
  nrows <- sapply(results, nrow) # get numbers of rows of each result (for the file1 example, this is (1, 1, ..., 1))
  ids <- rep(dat$ID, times = nrows) # make the ID column for the stacked results
  cbind(ID = ids, result)
}

## The shinyAPP ..........
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Stand"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    
    h3("Inputs"),
    
    numericInput("G", "G", min=0.00, max=300.00, value=25),
    numericInput("N", "N", min=100, max=1500, value=350),
    
    fileInput("file", "Upload file for batch computation", accept = ".csv"),
    
    actionButton("runScript", "Run")
  ),
  mainPanel(type="tabs",
            tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    dat <- read.csv(input$file$datapath) # read data from CSV file
    Data(dat) # assign it to the reactive value Data
  })
  
  dt <- eventReactive(input$runScript, {
    if(is.null(Data())) { # if no data has been uploaded
      func.(input$G, input$N)  
    } else {
      func_byID(Data())
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    dt()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Friday Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking on the checkmark). Otherwise your question is considered as non-answered by StackOverflow.